# Count purchases after occurrence of event in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

In the below dataframe I want to count the number of purchases after a promo has been done for each product. So for banana, the promo is done on 1-5-2018 and I want to receive the total number of purchases after it (8 times). How do I best do that efficiently in python?

```
     Date product  Purchase  Promo
0  01-01-2018  banana         1      0
1  01-02-2018   apple         2      0
2  01-03-2018   apple         3      0
3  01-04-2018  banana         4      0
4  01-05-2018  banana         1      1
5  01-06-2018  banana         3      0
6  01-07-2018   apple         1      0
7  01-08-2018  banana         4      0
8  01-09-2018  banana         1      0
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: How do we determine *promo date* of each product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use, with `cummax` to set the condition to be counted after promo equal to 1 then use `mask` to eliminate the promo itself:

```
df.groupby('product')\
  .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Promo'].cummax().mask(x['Promo']==1,0) == 1,
                         'Purchase'].sum())
```

Output:

```
product
apple     0
banana    8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `df.groupby('product').apply(lambda x : sum(x['Promo'].cumsum().shift().fillna(0)*x['Purchase']))` :-)